# Apps script email send with attachment based on a google drive url

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a google sheet document with a list of people, their emails, and a google drive url (column 40) that should be the attachment to the email.
I have been trying to play with the attchment but i cant get it to work.
Below you can find my function.
hope you guys can help.
thanks

```
function SendEmail() {
  var Activesheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var lastrow = Activesheet.getLastRow();
  var EmailTemplate = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Settings").getRange(9, 1).getValue();
  var DailyEmailQuota = MailApp.getRemainingDailyQuota();
  for (var i = 2; i <= lastrow; i++) {
    var Emaillist = Activesheet.getRange(i, 10).getValue();
    var EmailSubject = 'Re: ' + Activesheet.getRange(i, 2).getValue();
    var EmailPersonName = Activesheet.getRange(i, 7).getValue();
    var PropertyAddress = Activesheet.getRange(i, 2).getValue();
    var EmailBody = EmailTemplate.replace("{Name}", EmailPersonName).replace("{Property Address}", PropertyAddress);
    var attachment = Activesheet.getRange(i, 40).getValue();
    Logger.log(attachment);
    if (Emaillist === "") {
      return;
    }
    else {
      MailApp.sendEmail({
        name: 'Jonathan Kessous',
        to: Emaillist,
        subject: EmailSubject,
        htmlBody: EmailBody,
        attachments: [attachment],
      });
    }
  }
```

thanks
Jonathan

Comment: An attactment is `an array of files to send with the email`

Comment: OK. Is there any option to send attachment using the url that is in the specific cell that is at the current row?

the rows look like this
`
Date      Name        EMAIL ADDRESS   DETAILS   ATTACHMENT
8/7/22  John           123@google,com    client    GoogleDriveURL
9/7/22  Max             456@gmail.com      emp.    GoogleDriveURL
`
And i need that the email will be send with the attchment (if there is one) for each row.
thanks

Comment: [Here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#sendEmail(String,String,String,Object)) look it up for yourself